# How to deploy a SignalR application on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications, signalr, .net-6.0

I have a simple signalR application (hub is "/myNotifyHub") for sending notifications between clients. Language c#, .net 6.0 core. There are numerous examples out there for the same. But what they don't cover are,

1. How do I make sure the port is always constant? If it's not, how do I find the port? Maybe if deployed on IIS on website http://www.myinternalwebsite.com/ the client will automatically find the port when hitting "http://www.myinternalwebsite.com/myNotifyHub" ?
2. What is the process to deploy this signalR web application on the website mentioned above ?

Please don't point me to the Microsoft learn project, it does not cover the above as you can read in the comments for many of the similar questions in attack over flow for this topic.

Thanks in advance.

What's tried:

Tried to publish the application but the client is not able to resolve the hub url. It can connect to the base website.

Can only connect locally with swagger.

Comment: Why not Microsoft Learn articles? The ASP.NET Core in-process and out-of-process mode articles contain most information for these two questions.

Comment: What is IIS version? You might have to enable WebSockets there.

Comment: Yes websockets are enabled. Li - can you point me to articles please. :)

Answer (score 0):

By specifying the hub with the `/myNotifyHub` path, you are ensuring a specific URL for your SignalR hub.

Now, when your SignalR application is deployed to IIS and your website is accessible at `http://www.myinternalwebsite.com/`, your SignalR hub will be available at `http://www.myinternalwebsite.com/myNotifyHub`. The port will be managed by IIS and you don't need to worry about specifying it.

About deployment:

By default, Websocket support is not enabled on IIS. It was introduced in IIS 8 and must be enabled from Windows Optional Features: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support.

There is nothing special about hosting a website in IIS and hosting a SignalR website in IIS.

1. Start by publishing the application using an appropriate deployment method (e.g. publish to folder, etc.).
2. Copy the published files to the appropriate directory on the IIS server.
3. Configure your IIS site to point to the published folder.
4. Depending on your IIS setup, you may need to configure URL rewrite rules, if necessary, to ensure that SignalR requests are handled correctly.
5. If your SignalR hub is hosted on a different domain than your clients, make sure CORS is configured correctly to allow communication between them.